# How do i replace a key up keyCode with another in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, key, keycode

I currently have a table which only has a single editable column. I have a jQCuery change() event associated with the column's input controls to prevent any non numeric keys being pressed, other than tab / delete / backspace.

I would like to replace the Enter key with a Tab press.

Can someone please show me the relevant statement to replace the keyCode based on the Enter character being intercepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't replace it, but you can handle it, like this:

```
$(".myField").keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find("input").focus();
    return false; 
  }
});
```

Just modify the `$(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find("input").focus();` (currently going to the next row) portion to whatever your layout is, to find the next element you want to move to and focus it.

Comment: +1 - Nick, you're a SO troll... you seriously are all over this site

Comment: @Hunter - Working on jQuery 1000 badge, then I'll pick another category :)  Bugfixing at work leaves 5 minutes here and there to answer questions.

Comment: Sure, I just thought that if there was a way to emulate the other keypress I could handle it in my existing code without the expense of another dom lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are capturing the key's anyway, why not just move focus when the enter key is used rather than try to change keystrokes.

Comment: Sometimes you want a site-wide solution that you can just throw into a textbox's onkeydown (or other) event, so that you don't have to specify the field to receive focus.